# What is the command in tcl such as num2str in MATLAB?

Tags: tcl

What is the command in tcl such as num2str in MATLAB?
For example, I would like to repeat 10 process from "file1" to "file10" using for loop.
Please help me.

```
for {set i 1} {$i<11} {incr i} {
pw::Script source {C:/new/file1.glf }
pw::Application markUndoLevel {Run Script}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
for {set i 1} {$i<11} {incr i} {
    pw::Script source "C:/new/file${i}.glf"
    pw::Application markUndoLevel {Run Script}
}
```

Variables don't get expanded within braces.

This is a very basic question. You would benefit from reading through the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).